# A count of ForeignKey

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys, django-model-field

I have class `Team`, which means a group of users. And the relation with `User` is `One-to-Many`.

```
class Team(models.Model):
        member = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

But Team may consist of `2` and `N` members. I think to write manually is not our way, because it depends on count of people which is always variable.

```
 class Team(models.Model):
    member1 = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)   
    member2 = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    member3 = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

How can I do it more elegant and rational? I mean to connect `count` variable and `ForeignKeys` associating with users.

upd 15:17 UTC. I still don't understand how to make this. Sorry. So, let's begin to draw.
[image]

For example, I wrote simple code

```
class Event(models.Model):
    id_user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

But when I go to admin panel to add Event, I can add only one user. But I need to add a lot of users, who want to participate in the Event and then to divide them into Teams. I think I don't need another class Member. It seems unnecessary. Am I wrong?

Comment: If each user can only have one team, make the users attach to teams (ie put a team foreign key in the user object). If it is many-to-many, create a TeamConnection object which connects users and teams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you stated `Team` model, have `ManyToOne` relation that means ForeignKey.

> But Team may consist of 2 and N members.

You should create two models `Team` and `Member`. In `Member` model, you can store all information related to members such as their age, gender, city, etc.

In `Team` model, you can store information related to particular team which consists of more than one `Member` i.e. It has `ManyToOne` relation with `Member`.

`Models.py:`

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Member(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.user.username}"


class Team(models.Model):
    member = models.ForeignKey(Member, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

Registering in admin site:

`admin.py:`

```
@admin.register(Member)
class MemberAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['id', 'user'] #Also specify other fields.


@admin.register(Team)
class TeamAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['id', 'member'] #Also specify other fields.
```

---

---

---

## Edit:

According to the current picture, a `Event` can have more than one `Team` as well as more than one `User`. So, make two separate Foreign keys for both the models.

models.py

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Team(models.Model):
    # The below field is for name of team
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    # The below field is for member of team.
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.name}"


class Event(models.Model):
    # The below field is for name of event.
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    # The below field is for user of event.
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    # The below is for team of event.
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.name}"
```

admin.py

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Team, Event


@admin.register(Event)
class EventAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['id', 'name', 'user', 'team']


@admin.register(Team)
class TeamAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['id', 'name', 'user']
```

views.py

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Team, Event


def home(request):
    events = Event.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'any_app_name/home.html', {'events': events})
```

home.html or template file:

```html
<body>
    <h2>All team information.</h2>

    <div>
        {% for event in events %}
        <h3>{{forloop.counter}}</h3>
        <p>Name of event: {{event.name}}</p>
        <p>Name of user related to this event: {{event.user.username}}</p>
        <p>Name of team related to this event: {{event.team.name}}</p>
        <br><hr>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you, but how can I restrict user to apply differect class simultaneously during an Event, for example. I mean. I have Event, where several teams can participate. And one user can choose only one team. But. in another Event the user can choose another Team for the new Event.

Comment: @Sergo I think you should make a Event model for that.

Comment: Sunderam Dubey, thank you, but I'm sorry I didn't catch. Can you please explain if I have used User from 'django.contrib.auth.models import User' can I create a User class without overwriting the django class? I afraid errors, because I have importand data in my database.

Comment: @Sergo And yes, you can do, make a similar foreign key of member in Event Model.

Comment: I draw it in Paint:) I have one question. I see some opportuinities with your class Member. But how can I add new users automatically to class Member. I can do it only manually right now. It's not convenient. (I upvoted all your answers)

Comment: @Sergo To automatically add member you can use [`post_save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/signals/#post-save) signal.

Answer (score 2):

Create a team with one field team_name:

```
class Team(models.Model):
    team_name = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
```

and assign users to this team:

```
class User(models.Model):
    this_users_team = models.ForeignKey(Team, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

in this case you can assign as many Users to any team, as you want

Comment: Thx, but I haven't Uer class. I'm using User from django.contrib.auth.models import User..